# Get collection from object

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

In C#/.Net is there a way to reflect from an object, which is a member of a collection up to the collection itself so we can (a) iterate over the other members of the collection, and (b) assuming the collection is itself a member of a collection follow the tree back up to the root?

A typical example would be if there is a common attribute which can be set at multiple levels the collection tree and when an object is changed, find the nearest trunk entry.

Comment: No, there is not, unless your object explicitly stores a reference to its parent collection.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it is if the type you are working with explicitly has things in it to handle this, in winforms this is handled via the [`IComponent.Site`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icomponent.site(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Other libraries may use other standards.